# How to compute the percentage of the predicted labels in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

having a dataframe my goal is to compute the percentage of the predicted labels according to the following conditions:

- Percentage of the resources having the `manual_label` in `B@1` e.g. if the value from the col `manual_label` is in the col `baseline_1`
- Percentage of the resorces having the `manual_label` in `B@3` e.g. if the value from the col `manual_label` is in the col `baseline_1,baseline_2,baseline_3`
- Percentage of the predicted resources having the `manual_label` in `P@1` e.g. if the value from the col `manual_label` is in the col `label_1`
- Percentage of the predicted resorces having the `manual_label` in `P@3` e.g. if the value from the col `manual_label` is in the col `label_1,label_2,label_3`

The dataframe:

```
    manual_label  prediction  index  label_1  label_2  label_3 baseline_1 baseline_2 baseline_3
0              1           7      0        7        1        9          1          9          4
1              1           1      1        1        7        4          1          9          4
2              9           4      2        4        1        7          1          9          4
3              3           4      3        4        9        3          1          9          4
4              1           1      4        1        4        7          1          9          4
..           ...         ...    ...      ...      ...      ...        ...        ...        ...
496            1           1    496        1        7        3          1          9          4
497            1           1    497        1        4        7          1          9          4
498            4           7    498        4        7        1          1          9          4
499            4           1    499        7        4        1          1          9          4
500            1           1    500        1        7        4          1          9          4
```

by using this solution

```py
baseline_p1=0
baseline_p3=0
pred_p1=0
pred_p3=0

rows=final.shape[0]
for i in range(rows):
  gold = final.iloc[i]["manual_label"]
  baseline=[final.iloc[i]["baseline_1"], final.iloc[i]["baseline_2"],final.iloc[i]["baseline_3"]]
  for j in range(len(baseline)):
    baseline[j]=baseline[j].strip()
  predictions=[final.iloc[i]["label_1"], final.iloc[i]["label_2"],final.iloc[i]["label_3"]]
  for j in range(len(predictions)):
    predictions[j]=predictions[j]
  
  if (gold==baseline[0]):
    baseline_p1+=1
  if (gold in baseline):
    baseline_p3+=1
  if (gold==predictions[0]):
    pred_p1+=1
  if (gold in predictions):
    pred_p3+=1

print("Raw counts: B@1={} B@3={} P@1={} P@3={}",baseline_p1,baseline_p3,pred_p1,pred_p3)
print("Percentages: B@1={} B@3={} P@1={} P@3={}",baseline_p1/rows,baseline_p3/rows,pred_p1/rows,pred_p3/rows)
```

I'm able to obtain only the percentage of the `B@1` and `B@3`. For `P@1` and `P@3` as result I have `0.0`

```
Raw counts: B@1={} B@3={} P@1={} P@3={} 171 374 0 0
Percentages: B@1={} B@3={} P@1={} P@3={} 0.3413173652694611 0.7465069860279441 0.0 0.0
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to iterate over the rows, because you can work with Boolean series instead:

```py
manual_is_base1 = final.manual_label == final.baseline_1
manual_is_base2 = final.manual_label == final.baseline_2
manual_is_base3 = final.manual_label == final.baseline_3
manual_is_anybase = manual_is_base1 | manual_is_base2 | manual_is_base3

manual_is_pred1 = final.manual_label == final.label_1
manual_is_pred2 = final.manual_label == final.label_2
manual_is_pred3 = final.manual_label == final.label_3
manual_is_anypred = manual_is_pred1 | manual_is_pred2 | manual_is_pred3

baseline_p1 = sum(manual_is_base1)
baseline_p3 = sum(manual_is_anybase)

pred_p1 = sum(manual_is_pred1)
pred_p3 = sum(manual_is_anypred)
```

Anyway, I think the problem you had with calculating `pred_p1` and `pred_p3` is not due to your code, but rather due to a problem in your data. After deleting  `for j in range(len(baseline)): baseline[j]=baseline[j].strip()` from your code, I ran it on the snippet of the dataframe you posted, and it worked as expected.

The fact that you have those two lines in your code indicates that the baseline values in your data are strings, which is already a bad sign. Try to find out why and correct the data, so that pandas can cast them as a numeric type.